# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while fetching the name of method marked as test (using @test) in the before method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, testng

**Problem Statement**
I want to get the name of the method which is marked as the test method using @test in the @before test.

After researching, I found a solution & following is my implementation :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class myTestClass {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void configureEnvironment(){
         // does some basic tasks
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void configureTest(Method m){
         System.out.println("Test Case Name : "+m.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void TestABC(){}

    @Test 
    public void TestXYZ(){}

    @AfterTest
    public void testCleanUp(){
        //performs test clean up activities
    }
}
```

*PS: It's a typed in code for explanation purpose & therefore please ignore any syntax errors.*

I am expecting the following **Output** ::

```
Test Case Name : TestABC
Test Case Name : TestXYZ
```

Following is my **testng xml** ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <suite name="My_Test_Suite" parallel="false">
 <test name="My_TESTS">
    <classes>
      <class name="myPackage.myTestClass" />
    </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

However I am getting the following **exception** ::

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest configureTest
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:647)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:615)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
```

As per the TestNG documentation, this is a native dependency injection where either the info is injected by testng or by dataprovider. Since I want to use the testng approach, I have implemented the above solution.

Could anyone please provide their inputs as to what am I missing here & if there is any incorrect implementation.

*PS: I have seen many duplicate issues but nobody has reported this exception & therefore decided to file this question.*

Comment: Are you sure the @BeforeTest method takes an argument?  IIRC, all TestNG annotated methods do not take any arguments

Comment: Yes, that was my bad, I was supposed to you BeforeMethod as pointed in the answer below. Anyways, thanks @Ayman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missmatch `@BeforeTest` and `@BeforeMethod`. From [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations):

> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method
>   belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag is run.
>
> @BeforeMethod:
>   The annotated method will be run before each test method.

What you want is:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void configureTest(Method m){
     System.out.println("Test Case Name : "+m.getName());
}
```